# MVC - No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am getting error " No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'DependencyInjectionExample.Models.ProteinTrackingService" when I access the following URL http://localhost:57213/ProteinTracker/ . I have implemented Dependency Injection and using Unity but for some reason get this error when I try to access the ProteinTracker controller. Please find the code below

```
 public class ProteinTrackerController : Controller
    {

        private IProteinTrackingService proteinTrackingService ;


        public ProteinTrackerController(IProteinTrackingService proteinTrackingService)
        {
            this.proteinTrackingService = proteinTrackingService;
        }

        // GET: ProteinTracker
        public ActionResult Index(ProteinTrackingService model)
        {

            model.Total = proteinTrackingService.Total;
            return View(model);

        }

        // GET: ProteinTracker/Details/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddProtein(ProteinTrackingService model)
        {
            proteinTrackingService.AddProtein(model.Total);
            model.Total = proteinTrackingService.Total;

            return View("Index",model);
        }


    }
```

The ProteinTrackingService

```
 public class ProteinTrackingService : IProteinTrackingService
    {
        private IProteinRepository repository;

        public ProteinTrackingService(IProteinRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public int Total
        {
            get { return repository.GetData(new DateTime().Date).Total; }
            set { repository.SetTotal(new DateTime().Date, value); }
        }
        //public int Goal
        //{
        //    get { return repository.GetData(new DateTime().Date).Goal; }
        //    set { repository.SetGoal(),value; }
        //}

        public void AddProtein(int amount)
        {
            Total += amount;
        }
    }
```

The ProteinRepository

```
   public class ProteinRepository : IProteinRepository
    {
        private static ProteinData data = new ProteinData();
        public ProteinData GetData(DateTime date)
        {
            return data;
        }

        public void SetTotal(DateTime date, int value)
        {
            data.Total = value;
        }

        public void SetGoal(DateTime date, int value)
        {
            data.Goal = value;
        }

    }
```

The UnityConfig

```
  public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion


        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            //container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your types here

            container.RegisterType<IProteinTrackingService, ProteinTrackingService>();
            container.RegisterType<IProteinRepository, ProteinRepository>();

        }
    }

 public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `DependencyResolver.SetResolver()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes there is . One that was given when I installed Unity, Its in the UnityWebActivator class. I have updated the post to include that. When I try to call its start method from the Global.asax start method, it still doesnt help

Comment: You definitely aren't supposed to call `UnityWebActivator.Start()` manually in code. That's what `WebActivator` is for.

Comment: So if it calling it automatically then why isnt my container not getting loaded

Comment: I don't have an answer to that question. Just wanted to clarify the role of `WebActivator`. However, does the `[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(...)]` attribute defined?

Comment: Also, you're definitely not supposed to have `ProteinTrackingService` parameter in each of your actions.

Comment: Yes the [assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(...)] attribute is defined. Th reason why I am having the ProteinTrackingService parameter in both the methods is because of the following 1. I need to Initialise my model in the index method and pass it to the index view. 2.Need it in the AddProtein method because I need to pass the model that has been initialised in the view and ultimately save it to the database.